# Swift 3 using AFNetworking

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, afnetworking

I am using AFNetworking with Swift 3.0 and I am stuck on one code.

```
func getJSON()
    {


        let manager = AFHTTPSessionManager()
        manager.get(
            url,
            parameters: nil,
            success:
            {
                (operation: URLSessionTask!, responseObject: Any?) in

                 print("JSON: " + responseObject!.description)
                 self.matchesArray = responseObject!.object(forKey: "matches")! as? NSMutableArray
                 self.tollBothPlazaTableView.reloadData()
            },

            failure:
            {
                (operation: URLSessionTask!, error: NSError)  in
                print("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
            }
        )
    }
```

It shows error on `failure` block.

> Cannot convert value of type '(URLSessionTask!, NSError) -> ()' to expected argument type '((URLSessionDataTask?, Error) -> Void)?'`

Can someone explain what is wrong in my code. Also the correct way to use closures? (I am new to swift).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Error is clearly saying that use `Error` instead of `NSError`, in Swift 3 you need to use [`Error`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/error) instead of `NSError`. So change your code like below.

```
func getJSON() {

    let manager = AFHTTPSessionManager()
    manager.get(
        url,
        parameters: nil,
        success:
        {
            (operation, responseObject) in

             if let dic = responseObject as? [String: Any], let matches = dic["matches"] as? [[String: Any]] {
                  print(matches)
             }
             DispatchQueue.main.async {                          
                 self.tollBothPlazaTableView.reloadData()
             }
        },
        failure:
        {
            (operation, error) in
             print("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
    })
}
```

**Note:** Always perform UI changes on main thread when you are on background thread, so batter to reload your `tableView` on main thread like I have done, Also use Swift native `Array` and `Dictionary` instead of `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`.

Comment: Thank you. This solved it. So should I declare my array as Array and not NSMutableArray?

Comment: @thewarri0r9 Welcome mate, Declare your array as Array of dictionary like my answer if it contains dictionary like `var matchesArray = [[String:Any]]()`, declare it as String array if it contains String like `var matchesArray = [String]()`

Answer (score 4):

**Its Better to use Alamofire(same developer) in swift 3 **

```
func jsonRequest()
{

    let url =  "url"
    //if you want to add paramter
    parametr = ["username" : "user" , "password"]


    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
        .responseJSON { response in
            // print(response)
            //to get status code
            if let status = response.response?.statusCode {
                switch(status){
                case 201:
                    print("example success")
                default:
                    print("error with response status: \(status)")
                }
            }

            //to get JSON return value
            if let array = response.result.value as? //NSDictionary [[String : Any]]
            {


            }
    }

}
```

Comment: ok no problem but try Alamofire is better than Afnetworing :-) Happy Coding

Comment: But if you have a hybrid project, having two frameworks that do the same thing isn't always desired. AlamoFire is better and we use it in our Swift-only/mostly project - but if you have 90% ObjC - its just not practical.